# C++ Basic Calculator

Tags: c++

I'm new to C++ and programming in General. I was assigned to make a calculator for my C++ class and this is what I have so far.

```
#include <iostream>;
#include <iomanip>;
using namespace std;
int main() {
    double x,y;
    char op;
    cout << "Enter Expression:";
    cin >> x >> op >> y;
    if (op = '+')
    {
        cout << "Result:" << x + y << endl;
    }
    else if (op = '-') {
        cout << "Result:" << x - y << endl;
    }
    else if (op = '*') {
        cout << "Result:" << x*y << endl;
    }
    else if (op = '/') {
        cout << "Result:" << x / y << endl;
    }
    else if (op = '%') {
        cout << "Result:" << x % y << endl; // <--- line 23
    }
    else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

The x and y variables on line 23 both have errors saying that the expression must have an integral or unscoped enum type and I don't understand why.

Comment: `=` and `==` are different operations

Comment: % operator is for integer not double.

Answer (score 1):

You are using % for double, it is only for integers.
If you want to use same functionality for double. you can use fmod()

```
double z = fmod(x,y);
```

You should modify your code to below

```
 #include <iostream>;
 #include <iomanip>;
 using namespace std;
 int main() {
    double x,y;
    char op;
    cout << "Enter Expression:";
    cin >> x >> op >> y;
            if (op == '+')
        {
            cout << "Result:" << x + y << endl;
        }
            else if (op == '-') {
            cout << "Result:" << x - y << endl;
        }
            else if (op == '*') {
            cout << "Result:" << x*y << endl;
        }
            else if (op == '/') {
            cout << "Result:" << x / y << endl;
        }
            else if (op == '%') {
            cout << "Result:" << fmode(x,y) << endl;
        }
            else{
            return 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `%` operation is defined only for integer values. You cannot apply it for doubles. Also you have a typical novice mistake: In C++ `operator =` is assignment operator `a = b` mean get b value and put it in a. But `operator ==` is comparison operator, `a == b` mean if `a` equally `b` return `true`. If you want to compare values use `==`, not `=`.

Answer (score 1):

With floating point division there is no remainder. What should be the result of `2.5 % 1.2`?

You could use `int`s for that case:

```
    else if (op == '%') {
        cout << "Result:" << (int)x % (int)y << endl;
    }
```

but note that when the user types `2.5 % 1.2` this will show the result for `2 % 1`.

PS: Also note that you have `=` (assignment) in the conditions when it should be `==` (comparison).

Comment: Please do not use C-style casts in a C++ program, if you can help it.

Comment: @Striezel in general I do agree, but I dont see how it would make any difference here

Comment: People who are new to programming (and the person who asked that question said he is) tend to use the example code snippets that get thrown at them, because they do not know any better way yet. And if these examples use any obsolete / outdated coding styles (like C-casts, pointer to char instead of `std::string`, etc.), they just copy it and assume that is the normal way to do things. That is why I think one should not use such stuff even in small snippets, because they serve as bad example.

Comment: @Striezel ok you convinced me, if you want you can edit it, or I will do it later...

Answer (score 0):

The remainder operator `%` does not work for operands of type `double` (cf., for example, [cppreference.com/Multiplicative operators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic)):

> For the built-in operator `%`, lhs and rhs must both have integral or
>   unscoped enumeration type

You could write `static_cast<int>(x)%static_cast<int>(y)` instead.

Further, note that `=` is assignment operator; for comparisons (as in your case with `if (op = '%')`), use equality operator `==`, i.e. `if (op == '%')`.

Comment: Eeek. C-style casts. At *least* use proper C++ casts.. no need to make the situation more dangerous and unclear than it *has* to be.

Comment: @Jesper Juhl: agree in general; but is the situation really dangerous or unclear when casting primitive data type `double` to `int`?

Comment: perhaps not in this *specific* case, but since a C-style cast may degenerate into a `reinterpret_cast` of a `const_cast` of the variable in question, I'd consider it extremely dangerous and something to avoid *always* - even if provably safe in given circumstances. Definately not something to advice newbies to do. Also; the C++ casts are easier to `grep` for and are more explicit about the conversion being done ;-)